# How to remove the word "Figure" from listoffigures Latex?

Tags: latex, caption, figures

I'm searching a lot for this issue but it seems that it's not so simple.

I have my list of figures in Latex and right after the number of the figure there is the word "figure", just before the caption.

"1.1figure Evolution of.." How can I remove the word "figure"?

I have tried with

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{}
```

but nothing changes.

Thanks a lot

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper, english, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter

\let\l@table\l@figure

\graphicspath{{./figures/stateart/},{./figures/general/}}
\usepackage[list=true]{caption}
\usepackage[list=false]{subcaption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{} \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\input{chapters/Header}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}

\listoffigures
\listoftables\clearpage
\end{document}

Comment: Please read the linked post and make sure not to include completely unrelated content (like [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), for example). With the current code snippet, I'm unable to replicate your problem.

Comment: Fabio, missing `\makeatother` by the way!

Comment: is it possible to use regex?